# Is close() and channel.close() the same for channelFlow (or callbackFlow)?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow, kotlin-coroutine-channel

I have a callbackFlow below

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.callbackMerge(other: Flow<T>): Flow<T> = callbackFlow {
    channel.close()
    launch {
        collect { trySend(it) }
        channel.close()
    }
    other.collect { trySend(it) }
    awaitClose { println("Close Callback") }
}
```

I can use `channel.close()` or `close()`. They seem to behave the same to me.

Is there a different between them? When should I use which?

Comment: I believe they are the same, just use `close()` for conciseness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs of [`channel`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-producer-scope/channel.html) property say:

> A reference to the channel this coroutine sends elements to. It is
> provided for convenience, so that the code in the coroutine can refer
> to the channel as channel as opposed to this. All the SendChannel
> functions on this interface delegate to the channel instance returned by this property.

So basically they are the same due to delegation.